# Cubic Fit to Graph. How Do I create a better fit to my data and retrieve values from the fit?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, cubic

I have plotted some experimental data in Python and need to find a cubic fit to the data. The reason I need to do this is because the cubic fit will be used to remove background (in this case resistance in a diode) and you will be left with the evident features. Here is the code I am currently using to make the cubic fit in the first place, where Vnew and yone represent arrays of the experimental data.

```
answer1=raw_input ('Cubic Plot attempt?\n ')

    if answer1 in['y','Y','Yes']:


        def cubic(x,A):
            return A*x**3

        cubic_guess=array([40])               
        popt,pcov=curve_fit(cubic,Vnew,yone,cubic_guess)

        plot(Vnew,cubic(Vnew,*popt),'r-',label='Cubic Fit: curve_fit')
        #ylim(-0.05,0.05)   
        legend(loc='best')
        print 'Cubic plotted'
    else:
        print 'No Cubic Removal done'
```

I have knowledge of curve smoothing but only in theory. I do not know how to implement it. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Here is the graph generated so far:

[image]

Comment: The way you're doing it is correct. What exactly is the problem? You get the best possible fit (in the least-squares definition) to your one-parameter model. This will be in `popt` (which will differ from your initial guess of 40). You can extract the new y-data values as you did in the plot, with `cubic(Vnew,*popt)`.

Comment: How can I force the cubic fit to become "wider" to accommodate the parts of the data the cubic is "crossing over"?

I feel like I should try a method that "blanks out" the features seen (around 0.25 V for example) and do a fit on what I consider to be ONLY the background?

Answer (score 0):

To make the fitted curve "wider", you're looking for extrapolation. Although in this case, you could just make `Vnew` cover a larger interval, in which case you'd put this before your `plot` command:

```
Vnew = numpy.linspace(-1,1, 256)  # min and max are merely an example, based on your graph
plot(Vnew,cubic(Vnew,*popt),'r-',label='Cubic Fit: curve_fit')
```

"Blanking out" the feature you see, can be done with [numpy's masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) but also just by removing those elements you don't want from both your original `Vnew` (which I'll call `xone`) and `yone`:

```
mask = (xone > 0.1) & (xone < 0.35)  # values between these voltages (?) need to be removed
xone = xone[numpy.logical_not(mask)]
yone = yone[numpy.logical_not(mask)]
```

Then redo the curve fitting:

```
popt,_ = curve_fit(cubic, xone, yone, cubic_guess)
```

This will have fitted only to the data that was actually there (which aren't that many points in your dataset, from the looks of it, so beware!).